# model organism for maize

Tags: transcription-factor

Since I am trying to find the functions of some transcription factors of the maize,  I would like to try a search on the model organism transcription factor databases.  Which model organism would anybody suggest?

Edit:
Sorry for the incomplete information provided.  Since a transcription factor database could provide the experimentally verified information about the model organism, some transcription factors of the maize have one defined function, e.g. matters about flowering and I would like to know the transcription binding in the model organism in order to clarify the function of these transcription factors.  As a result, I could connect these functions dot to dot instead of carrying out the actual experiments.

The model organism provided in the ans. helps me limit the further searches and helps me use the right algorithm to relate the transcription binding of different plants, e.g.  I could relate the transcription factor of flowering in maize to the similar `motif` in model plant (organism).

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [maize itself](https://www.grassius.org/grasstfdb.php)? (And other grasses)

If for some reason you need something that is more explicitly a model organism, I suppose you could look at [Arabidopsis](http://planttfdb.gao-lab.org/). That link actually includes a large number of plants, but Arabidopsis is almost certainly the best described.

But the maize data itself should be quite good (as well as containing orthologs from other *Graminaceae*.